# Handle cmd + q in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I want to quit my app with cmd +  q. How can I trigger this? 
Just need to execute this:

```
NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
```

How can I gain the button press?

Comment: Cocoa app with GUI, or command line app? Please add details about your context.

Comment: It's a GUI with buttons, tables, rows, etc. - is there something else you need for clarification?

Comment: Did you remove the `MainMenu.xib`? Because any Cocoa app with a MainMenu will automatically catch CMD+Q and send the Quit signal. Or maybe you're intercepting key presses? Please give us more details, as Vadian said it's hard to help without clear explanations of your issue... :)

Comment: Whoops, it was hidden....found it in the Interface Builder. I made an IBAction on "Quit XYZ" cmd + q button within the menu bar and it works. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In Interface Builder connect the action of the `Quit` `NSMenuItem` to First Responder (red cube) > `terminate:` and assign the key command.

Comment: Why kind of app are you using? Key commands work only if the application is active (frontmost).

Comment: That sounds logical for me. The app is running in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

The MainMenu.xib file within the Interface builder was hidden. You need to connect the "Quit XYZ" button (XYZ is the name of your app) with the MainWindowController and get the following into the IBAction:

```
    // Kill app when cmd + q has been pressed.
@IBAction func termianteApp(_ sender: Any) {
    NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)

}
```